# JMS - Sending object message

Tags: jms

I want to send object message in jms and getting run time exception.
Please suggest me possible solutions.

JMS Code:

```
ObjectMessage objMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
        MessageData data = new MessageData();
        objMessage.setObject(data);
        sender.send(objMessage);
```

Exception found on console:

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger         org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: com.test.SendJMSMessage
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.messaging.util.StreamUtils.writeObject(StreamUtils.java:249)
at org.jboss.jms.message.JBossObjectMessage.doWriteObject(JBossObjectMessage.java:141)
at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.message.MessageSupport.getPayloadAsByteArray(MessageSupport.java:216)
at org.jboss.jms.message.JBossObjectMessage.setObject(JBossObjectMessage.java:118)
at org.jboss.jms.message.ObjectMessageProxy.setObject(ObjectMessageProxy.java:59)
at com.test.SendJMSMessage.example(SendJMSMessage.java:36)
at com.test.SendJMSMessage.main(SendJMSMessage.java:130)
```

After creating new MessageData class in place of creating subclass MessageData, when I run the code I got exceptions as below:

```
18:26:08,297 ERROR [JmsGatewayListener] Problems invoking method <process>
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.gateway.JmsGatewayListener.doRun(JmsGatewayListener.java:161)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.lifecycle.AbstractThreadedManagedLifecycle.run(AbstractThreadedManagedLifecycle.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No ClassLoaders found for: com.test.MessageData
at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:306)
at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.messaging.util.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:78)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.messaging.util.StreamUtils.readObject(StreamUtils.java:154)
at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.message.MessageSupport.readPayload(MessageSupport.java:405)
at org.jboss.jms.message.JBossObjectMessage.getObject(JBossObjectMessage.java:126)
at org.jboss.jms.message.ObjectMessageProxy.getObject(ObjectMessageProxy.java:68)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.gateway.PackageJmsMessageContents.setESBMessageBody(PackageJmsMessageContents.java:165)
at org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.gateway.PackageJmsMessageContents.process(PackageJmsMessageContents.java:89)
... 7 more
```

Here I am trying to send an object message to esb server code.
Any suggestions on console window as above please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class MessageData needs to implement java.io.Serializable. Could that be the issue?  There should be an additional "cause" exception stack trace.

Comment: MessageData class implemnents java.io.serializable interface but still same issue.

Answer (score 6):

The exception is at "the other side":

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.messaging.util.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:78)
```

So you did send the message, but you are unable to deserialize it at the other end. Why? Because the "other side" does not have the class definition of `MessageData` in its classpath. If it's a different application, you need to extract `MessageData` to a common jar and have it included in both applications.

Serialization is no magic; both serializing and deserializing party must have access to the same class definition (.class file) and their versions must be the same, or at least compatible.

Comment: How do i ensure that the same object is not created as two differnt object message ...

Comment: How is that relevant to the problem? What case do you have in mind?

Comment: I am querying db and sending the data as objects to the client via queue.I need to ensure that the same row/object is not returned to the user at any point of time.